# What is a “spectator mode” in this analysis of molecular vibration modes

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I'm reading a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp206893n) in which I found this line:

> The other modes have relatively small contributions for the displacements of the heavy atoms and can be considered as spectator modes for the internal conversion

I cannot find a definition or explanation of term “spectator mode”. What is it exactly?

Comment: I suppose they may have invented it. I would assume that they took the term from spectator ions.

Comment: There is no such term, in that you won't find it in the dictionaries. This is just a combination of two words, and if you know the meaning of each word, then you know what do they mean when put together.

Comment: Without the paper its hard to follow this, also the English is not that clear, 'for the displacements' or ' towards the displacements', but it implies that these modes are not the promoting mode(s) in the radiationless conversion, i.e they don't take part, hence 'spectator'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper in question is [*Ab Initio Trajectory Surface-Hopping Study on Ultrafast Deactivation Process of Thiophene*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp206893n). From a quick [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22spectator+mode%22+vibration) that returns 187 hits, it is clear that the expression *“spectator mode”* for a harmonic vibration mode is not a standard terminology, but is nonetheless used by plenty of authors.

As to the meaning, I think you got it from the everyday meaning of “spectator”: they are vibration modes that do not participate in the phenomenon of interest, i.e. that are not coupled to the chemical or physical process studied (which can be a chemical reaction, an adsorption process or a photophysical process).